# TFS behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, tfs, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

Trying to configure Team Foundation Server behind Nginx reverse proxy.
Also, I'm using a self-signed SSL Certificate.

Getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name tfs.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;    
}

upstream tfs.domain.com {
        server 12.34.56.78:80; #local tfs address
        keepalive 16;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name tfs.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tfs.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tfs.domain.com.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://12.34.56.78:80; #local tfs address
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;

    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/tfs.domain.com/443-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/tfs.domain.com/443-error.log;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to set the `proxy_redirect` explicitly:

e.g.:

```
proxy_redirect  http://localhost:8080 https://tfs.domain.com;
```

You can reference below article to configure the nginx (It should be similar with TFS):

[How To Configure Nginx with SSL as a Reverse Proxy for Jenkins](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins)

And this thread may helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/754351/what-is-a-correct-ways-to-allow-login-to-an-iis-site-through-a-reverse-proxy

Besides, you can reference below articles to troubleshoot the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` issue:

- [How to Fix ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Your WordPress Site](https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/#redirects-on-server)
- [How to Fix Err Too Many Redirects Error](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-err-too-many-redirects-error/)

Comment: @Leonid Usachov Have you resolved the issue? any update?